# Blackberry Images not working with phonegap/jquery Mobile on OS 5.x

Tags: blackberry, jquery-mobile, cordova, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks

I have been trying to write a simple map application using phonegap and jquery Mobile. Using static Google Maps API i am able to load the map and display it in the emulator(ripple on chrome and the webworks simulator). But when i am using on any of the actual ![enter image description hereblackberry OS 5.X devices none of the images are getting rendered.

Anyone can guide me with this ?

Please refer below screenshots from the emulator

[image]

Actual Device
 is this renders as below

[image: Actual Device]

Comment: Hi, Wich is the version of BB OS running in the device?

Comment: I have tested in on OS 5.0 , it didn't work. I tried it on OS 6.0 today, same issue.

Answer (score 0):

For the record:

There is a workaround to this issue:

Try to give a timeout so that image is preloaded. 
$("#map").attr("src", "newimagepath/img.jpg") 
setTimeout(function(){ 
                    $("#map").css("display", "block") 
            }, 600);

If images are static, you could do javascript image preload:

img = new Image()

img.src = "newimagepath/img.jpg"

and then use "newimagepath/img.jpg"  at a later stage. 
Both above worked well for me.

Thanks to Srini from the Google Group of Phonegap:
http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/d9c2c08b5f7b6423/5a4095c48a7ba833?lnk=gst&q=blackberry+image#5a4095c48a7ba833